# Difference between だの and など/とか

Tags: word-usage

I'm reading an old book (こころ by 夏目漱石) and there's an unfamiliar grammatical phrasing that has fallen out of fashion and/or that he was rather fond of: ~だの~だの, e.g.:

。。。イサベラ何何の墓**だの**、神僕ロギンの墓**だの**というかたわらに。。。

The dictionary I use suggests it's similar to など/とか in meaning&usage. Are there any important differences?

Comment: I don't know if there are any important differences, but I have the impression that "私" (or the authour himself) has a negative feeling toward  grave markers. The subsequent passage has it as  先生はこれらの墓標が現わす人種々の様式に対して、私ほどに滑稽もアイロニーも認めてないらしかった。 (Excerpt from http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/773_14560.html.)

Comment: Does this help? https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0eprLex8sr0C&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A&source=bl&ots=4KGos_Dwsz&sig=1B_o6ku85EMmSwtkXQYud0wzdOI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3WSbVdC3EsGmmAWizpjIDA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A&f=false 「こころ」が書かれた頃が「現在」に入るかどうかわかりませんが。

Comment: What leads you to think it might have "fallen out of fashion"?

Comment: @dainichi I've never seen (perhaps noticed?) it before, and the first time I come across it is in a 100-year-old book... I'd love to see an n-grams, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There indeed exists a fairly important difference between 「～～だの～～だの」 and the other juxtaposition structures such as 「～～とか～～とか」、「～～や～～など」、「～～とか～～など」, etc.

The difference is that 「～～だの～～だの」 would generally imply the speaker's negative feelings about the items being juxtaposed all by itself ***even without using further negative words around it***.

The other forms of juxtaposition do not carry either a positive or negative connotation all by themselves.  That value judgement would need to be expressed with other wordings around them.

**To put it in the simplest terms possible, you are complaining about something 95% of the time you use 「～～だの～～だの」.**

By "negative feelings" in this case, I am referring to juxtaposing:

1) worthless items or statements by the speaker's judgement (I did not mention juxtaposing statements above but it is a feature of the だのだの form.)

2) unrealistic and/or unsubstantial items by the speaker's judgement

In OP's example, the 「何何」 part of 「イサベラ何何の墓だの」 alone already expresses the speaker's negative feeling, IMHO.