# meaning and function of だの

Tags: grammar

I tried to translate the sentence:

> 世間では俺みたいな奴の事を引き篭もりだのネトゲ廃人**だの**と呼んでいるらしいが

My try:

> In this world, I am called a game junkie, which
> is to say “hikikomori” for such people like me

Is the だの similar to　という　?

is there a relation between の事を (earlier in the sentence) and  だの ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are parsing this sentence incorrectly. The basic structure is:

> AをBと呼んでいる
> call A (as) B

where A = 世間では俺みたいな奴の事 and B = 引き篭もり**だの**ネトゲ廃人**だの**.

For the meaning of だの (note that there are two of them but you only highlighted one as causing you problems) see [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25554/difference-between-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AE-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B).

Overall translation:

> Society calls people like me things like shut-ins and game junkies.

I'm using your translation of game junkie because I honestly have no idea how to translate ネトゲ廃人.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is much more clearer, I did not even remark the structure だの ... だの .. I thought it was something else, thanks for pointing the reference; as for the translation of ネトゲ廃人., it is not really important, litterally "net game disabled person" or "MMO fanatic" or whatever, I am much more interested by the grammatical structure;