# Meaning of ~だのと in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, syntax

I encountered this sentence in a manga and can't quite parse it:

> 情だの何だのと乳繰り合ってるようなヤツらは踏み台にすればいい

Context: a woman is jealous about her love interest getting close with another person (and meeting unbeknownst to her), and is plotting against them to advance at work (they all work at the same company).

I understand 情だの何だの means "feelings and what not", but I don't understand how と is working with 乳繰り合う here. Does it mean something like, "people having secret affairs to talk about feelings and what not should be used as stepping stones"?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93201/question-about-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%ae?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Here 情 is a word with a deep meaning similar to "sympathy", "compassion" or "humanity". Apparently, it's used as an example of words that sound nice but don't help solve real problems.
- だの is yet another listing particle in Japanese, and it is used to express the speaker's negative feelings. 何だの is just "or something". See: [Difference between だの and など/とか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25554/5010) and  [meaning and function of だの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82612/5010)
- Probably this 乳繰り合う is used sarcastically and should not be taken literally. It's used in place of something negative like "to quibble", "to only talk about the ideal", "to lick each other's wound", "to hide and say stupid things" or such. You really need to read between the lines here.
- This と is a "quotative-like" と that specifies how 乳繰り合う is done. See: [Function of と when used with 続く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68125/5010)

Thus the whole sentence roughly means "Those who only talk nonsense about sympathy or something should be used as stepping stones".

Comment: Ah, thank you for the great breakdown!  乳繰り合う being sarcastic makes much more sense given the situation. Cheers!